# Reusable UITableViewCells appear null, despite having labels and buttons

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am setting up a table view with this code:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UILabel *text = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 40)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:text];
        text.tag = 1;
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    UILabel *text = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    text.text = [subjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

It worked fine until I tried to make make cells reusable in the if(!cell) statement, somebody knows what is the problem.
To make the cells reusable I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843226/data-of-uitableviewcell-overlapping-with-each-other-on-scrolling) and, I think, copied correctly.

Comment: Are you using Storyboards and Prototype Cells? If so, everything in the `if(!cell) { ... }` can be deleted as a cell is guaranteed to be dequeued. Also, are you subclassing the table view cell? Personally, I recommend you do use Storyboards and Prototype Cells + subclassing the table view cell.

Comment: Also, if you are new to iOS and Objective-C, I recommend you look at the latest Stanford iOS 7 course on iTunesU - it is called `Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}  
for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
[view removeFromSuperview];
}
UILabel *text = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 40)];
[cell.contentView addSubview:text];
text.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
text.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
if(subjects[indexPath.row].lenght==0)
{
text.text=@"this object is null";
}
else
{
text.text = subjects[indexPath.row];
}
return cell;
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: I ran it like that: the cells are there because you can scroll through them, but its the labels aren't

Comment: do you mean label disappeared? if so please add this in cell configure and if still labels are not there i'll send a sample code (complete one) text.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
text.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are mixing up cells that are created from a storyboard and the cells that are created programmatically in your `if` branch:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

With this line you create a brand new `UITableViewCell` with the identifier `CellIdentifier`. In the `if` block you are only adding a `UILabel` to that cell's view, no buttons etc.

At the same time I assume you have set up a prototype cell in your storyboard (interface builder) with the same identifier. And that cell does have buttons etc.

But those two are different cells! The cell programmatically created does not know about the prototype cell in the storyboard. But you are giving them both the same reuse identifier.

***Analogy:*** It's like defining a car and a motorcycle both as "vehicles" (= reuse identifier) and then after creating a new motorcycle wondering why this particular vehicle has only two wheels. (Here the car is the equivalent to the prototype cell that you create in the storyboard with labels, buttons etc. and the motorcycle is the cell that you create programmatically.)

In this case you do not need to check if the cell is `nil` because the method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` will *always* return a valid `UITableViewCell` (that is if you have set up a prototype cell with that particular cell identifier in the storyboard). The method will automatically create a new cell instance if there is no reusable cell available. (See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14865308/2062785).)

Comment: Can you please add some information then what is actually happening? Does your table view still show a cell but with no contents? Or what exactly do you mean with "cell appears null"?

Comment: I have added another reply that should solve the problem under the assumption that you are using a storyboard / interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

try this in cellForRow:

```
UILabel *text = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 40)];
text.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
text.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Then run to see, if cell textLabels appear with black background and size is (300, 40), and white text on it.

If have no black lines, means textLabels do not be added properly.

If have no white text, means `subjects` is nil or it contains empty string.